# Performance Counter - Cant seem to get the correct NextValue

Tags: c#, winforms, perfmon

I have a windows service that has some performance counters in it. I have another application that monitors what the service is doing, including the performance counters that way everything is found and available in one place. However I seem to be having an issue with one of the performance counters of type RateOfCountsPerSecond32. If I look at the counters on Perfmon everything seems fine, this particular counter gives a reasonable value, but in my monitoring application the counter always provides 0 as its NextValue.

Below is the code i'm using to retrieve the counters from the given category:

```
        PerformanceCounterCategory pcc = new PerformanceCounterCategory(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        string stats = string.Empty;

        foreach (var counter in pcc.GetCounters())
        {
            stats += string.Format("{0}:\t {1} : {2}\r\n\r\n", counter.CounterName, counter.NextValue(), counter.RawValue );
        }

        lblTps.Text = stats;
```

This only seems to be an issue with this particular type of Counter.

Can anyone else notice anything wrong with this?  (other than that I should be using a StringBuilder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx):

> If the calculated value of a counter depends on two counter reads, the first read operation returns 0.0.

You have to call **NextValue()** twice after creating this type of counter because it needs to buffer one sample before computing its first value. Subsequent calls to **NextValue()** will work as expected.

Comment: So this sits in a loop and is performed once a second...but regardless of how long i let it run it always says 0.

Comment: You must call **NextValue()** twice on the same PerformanceCounter object to make it work. I'm afraid you are creating new PerformanceCounter instances each time you call **NextValue()** in that loop of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found to get a Rate counter to return a rate via code. Regardless of the Sleep time in button2_click, it displays a value of 4, which is about right for a 250ms delay in the "loop" code. The trick appears to be to compare the current and previous raw values over the time between the two samples.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => loop());

        using (PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("TestCounters", "RateTest", true))
        {
            CounterSample a = pc.NextSample();
            while (true)
            {               
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                CounterSample b = pc.NextSample();
                Single deltaTime = Convert.ToSingle(b.CounterTimeStamp / b.CounterFrequency - a.CounterTimeStamp/a.CounterFrequency);
                Single deltaRaw = Convert.ToSingle(b.RawValue - a.RawValue);
                label1.Text = (deltaRaw / deltaTime).ToString();
                b = a;
            }
        }
    }

    private void loop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            using (PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("TestCounters", "RateTest", false))
            {
                pc.Increment();
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }
```